# The cookie removes itself at page change or reload

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

I create a button to change theme on my site and I would like the chosen theme to be saved in a cookie. The cookie works well, but when I change page or I reload it, the cookie will be removed.

Here are my codes

My code :
Include file :
https://code.alwyn974.re/ohuwepalab.xml 
Darkmod.php
https://code.alwyn974.re/ecidexeqiv.xml
Darkmodpp.php 
https://code.alwyn974.re/zofekeqate.xml (for create cookie)
Checkcookie.php https://code.alwyn974.re/sakonojaxa.xml

```js
function Darkmod() {
  xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  if (document.body.className === 'dark') {
    theme = 'dark';
  } else {
    theme = 'light';
  }
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      var res = this.response;
      if (res.success == 1) {
        const body = document.querySelector('body');
        body.classList.toggle('dark');
      } else if (res.success == 2) {
        const body = document.querySelector('body');
        body.classList.toggle('dark');
      } else {
        alert('ERREUR LORS DU CHANGEMENT DE THEME');
      }
    } else if (this.readyState == 4) {
      alert("Une erreur est survenue lors du changement de theme !  Contactez l'administrateur réseau ou allez voir <a href=\"info#theme\">ici</a>");
    }
  }
  xhr.open("GET", "php/darkmodpp.php?theme=" + theme, true);
  xhr.responseType = "json";
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xhr.send();
};
```

```html
<script src="https://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="luminon" onclick="Darkmod()"></div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor. HERE!

Comment: Just use localStorage. No need to use cookies in 2020